# mysql stored procedure returns 0 rows affected

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to run a stored procedure in mysql, and it's returning 0 rows.  the individual selects work fine, and they also work fine as a group together. When run together, they create a series of temporary tabels and then return a final table at the end. Again, all is working fine. I've looked at other questions and am not seeing the error in my query.

My query:

```
    USE leeds_so;

#### OPEN STORED PROCEDURE
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE LadderConversionUpDown3()
    BEGIN 

#### DROP TABLES IF NEEDED
    DROP TABLE cte_leenk_ladder_history;
    DROP TABLE cte_ladder_value_between; 
    DROP TABLE cte_most_recent_record; 
    DROP TABLE cte_most_recent_record_ladder_level;
    DROP TABLE cte_ladder_value_before;
    DROP TABLE cte_most_recent_record_before; 
    DROP TABLE cte_most_recent_record_before_ladder_level; 
    DROP TABLE cte_additions_to_current_rung;
    DROP TABLE cte_before_additions_count; 
    DROP TABLE cte_sum_additions_to_ladder; 

#### CREATE PARAMETERS FOR LADDERS
SET @ladder_type = 'ladder_advocacy'; # remove in data studio 

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_leenk_ladder_history
        SELECT 
        member_id
        ,ladder_change
        ,date_trigger_event
        ,@ladder_type
        ,CASE WHEN @ladder_type='ladder_advocacy' THEN ladder_advocacy
                WHEN @ladder_type='ladder_elected' THEN ladder_elected
                WHEN @ladder_type='ladder_policy' THEN ladder_policy
                WHEN @ladder_type='ladder_organizing' THEN ladder_organizing
                WHEN @ladder_type='ladder_collective' THEN ladder_collective
                WHEN @ladder_type='ladder_engagement' THEN ladder_engagement
            END
            AS ladder_value
        FROM leeds_new.leenk_ladder_history;

#### GET CURRENT LADDER INFO 

# 1. Get member_id AND ladder hist value between X dates ## NEED TO FIX DATES IN DATA STUDIO 
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_ladder_value_between
        SELECT
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.member_id AS member_id,
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.date_trigger_event

        FROM cte_leenk_ladder_history
            WHERE cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_change = 1 AND cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_value IS NOT NULL
            AND date_trigger_event BETWEEN CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-06-01' AS DATE);

# 2. First get members most recent record date
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_most_recent_record
        SELECT
        cte_ladder_value_between.member_id AS member_id,
        MAX(cte_ladder_value_between.date_trigger_event) AS date_trigger_event_max

        FROM cte_ladder_value_between
        GROUP BY cte_ladder_value_between.member_id;

# 3. Get the rung value for the most recent ladder level
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_most_recent_record_ladder_level
        SELECT
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.member_id,
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_value,
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.date_trigger_event

        FROM cte_leenk_ladder_history
            INNER JOIN
                cte_most_recent_record ON cte_leenk_ladder_history.member_id = cte_most_recent_record.member_id
                AND cte_leenk_ladder_history.date_trigger_event = cte_most_recent_record.date_trigger_event_max
        WHERE cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_change = 1 AND cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_value IS NOT NULL;

#### GET LADDER IMMEDIATELY BEFORE 

# 4. Get member_id AND ladder hist value between X dates BEFORE
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_ladder_value_before
        SELECT
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.member_id AS member_id,
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.date_trigger_event

        FROM cte_leenk_ladder_history
            WHERE cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_change = 1 AND cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_value IS NOT NULL
            AND date_trigger_event < CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE);

# 5. First get members most recent record date BEFORE
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_most_recent_record_before
        SELECT
        cte_ladder_value_before.member_id AS member_id,
        MAX(cte_ladder_value_before.date_trigger_event) AS date_trigger_event_max

        FROM cte_ladder_value_before
        GROUP BY cte_ladder_value_before.member_id;

# 6. Get the rung value for the most recent ladder level BEFORE
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_most_recent_record_before_ladder_level
        SELECT
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.member_id,
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_value,
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.date_trigger_event

        FROM cte_leenk_ladder_history
            INNER JOIN
                cte_most_recent_record_before ON cte_leenk_ladder_history.member_id = cte_most_recent_record_before.member_id
                AND cte_leenk_ladder_history.date_trigger_event = cte_most_recent_record_before.date_trigger_event_max
        WHERE cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_change = 1 AND cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_value IS NOT NULL;

#### COUNT CURRENT & BEFORE LADDERS, THEN DIFFERENCE 

# 7. current period counts
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_additions_to_current_rung
        SELECT
            cte_most_recent_record_ladder_level.ladder_value,
            COUNT(cte_most_recent_record_ladder_level.ladder_value) AS additions_to_current_rung

        FROM cte_most_recent_record_ladder_level
        GROUP BY cte_most_recent_record_ladder_level.ladder_value;

# 8. before COUNTs
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_before_additions_count
        SELECT
            cte_most_recent_record_before_ladder_level.ladder_value,
            COUNT(cte_most_recent_record_before_ladder_level.ladder_value) AS before_additions_count

        FROM cte_most_recent_record_before_ladder_level
        GROUP BY cte_most_recent_record_before_ladder_level.ladder_value;

# 9. SUM additions to rung + before additions 
        SELECT
            cte_additions_to_current_rung.ladder_value,
            additions_to_current_rung,
            before_additions_count,
            additions_to_current_rung + before_additions_count AS total_ladder_counts
        FROM cte_additions_to_current_rung
            INNER JOIN cte_before_additions_count ON cte_additions_to_current_rung.ladder_value = cte_before_additions_count.ladder_value;

# 10. ADD: HOW MANY WERE LOST IN TIME PERIOD 
### as to figure this one out 


#### END STORED PROCEDURE 
    END // 
DELIMITER ;
```

Expected result (this returns outside fo the stored procedure):

[image]

Does anyone know what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: You never return anything at the end, all you do is create temporary tables.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add that note. I tried it with query 9 having w/ and w/o a temporary table. 

Both options return 0 rows.

Comment: Please also post expected result?? are you after SQL diagnostic results?

Comment: fixed teh query above to reflect no temp table at query 9. 

still returns 1 rows.

Comment: If it's not returning anything, then the query must not match anything. What happens if you try that query outside the procedure?

Comment: Updating teh above with expected and what happens if I run the query out of the procedure.

Comment: @Barmar updated, thoughts?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0)?

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. Made slight changes and it worked:

```
#### OPEN STORED PROCEDURE
CREATE PROCEDURE LadderConversionUpDown9()
    BEGIN 

### set parameter at top of stored procedure - alissa will also look it up; sam will look it up for 12/12 

#### DROP TABLE IF EXISTS IF NEEDED
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cte_leenk_ladder_history;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cte_ladder_value_between; 
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cte_current_record_date; 
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cte_current_record_ladder_level;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cte_ladder_value_before_current;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cte_ladder_date_before_current_period; 
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cte_ladder_level_before_current_period; 
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cte_additions_to_current_rung;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cte_start_of_period_count; 
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cte_sum_additions_to_ladder; 

#### CREATE PARAMETERS FOR LADDERS
SET @ladder_type = 'ladder_advocacy'; # remove in data studio 

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_leenk_ladder_history
        SELECT 
        member_id
        ,ladder_change
        ,date_trigger_event
        ,@ladder_type
        ,CASE WHEN @ladder_type='ladder_advocacy' THEN ladder_advocacy
                WHEN @ladder_type='ladder_elected' THEN ladder_elected
                WHEN @ladder_type='ladder_policy' THEN ladder_policy
                WHEN @ladder_type='ladder_organizing' THEN ladder_organizing
                WHEN @ladder_type='ladder_collective' THEN ladder_collective
                WHEN @ladder_type='ladder_engagement' THEN ladder_engagement
            END
            AS ladder_value
        FROM leeds_new.leenk_ladder_history;

#### GET CURRENT LADDER INFO 

# 1. Get member_id AND ladder hist value between X dates ## NEED TO FIX DATES IN DATA STUDIO 
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_ladder_value_between
        SELECT
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.member_id AS member_id,
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.date_trigger_event

        FROM cte_leenk_ladder_history
            WHERE cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_change = 1 AND cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_value IS NOT NULL
            AND date_trigger_event BETWEEN CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-06-01' AS DATE);

# 2. First get members CURRENT record date
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_current_record_date
        SELECT
        cte_ladder_value_between.member_id AS member_id,
        MAX(cte_ladder_value_between.date_trigger_event) AS date_trigger_event_max

        FROM cte_ladder_value_between
        GROUP BY cte_ladder_value_between.member_id;

# 3. Get the rung value for the CURRENT ladder level
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_current_record_ladder_level
        SELECT
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.member_id,
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_value,
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.date_trigger_event

        FROM cte_leenk_ladder_history
            INNER JOIN
                cte_current_record_date ON cte_leenk_ladder_history.member_id = cte_current_record_date.member_id
                AND cte_leenk_ladder_history.date_trigger_event = cte_current_record_date.date_trigger_event_max
        WHERE cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_change = 1 AND cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_value IS NOT NULL;

#### GET LADDER IMMEDIATELY BEFORE CURRENT PERIOD

# 4. Get member_id AND ladder hist value between X dates BEFORE CURRENT PERIOD 
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_ladder_value_before_current
        SELECT
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.member_id AS member_id,
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.date_trigger_event

        FROM cte_leenk_ladder_history
            WHERE cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_change = 1 AND cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_value IS NOT NULL
            AND date_trigger_event < CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE);

# 5. First get members most recent record date BEFORE current period
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_ladder_date_before_current_period
        SELECT
        cte_ladder_value_before_current.member_id AS member_id,
        MAX(cte_ladder_value_before_current.date_trigger_event) AS date_trigger_event_max

        FROM cte_ladder_value_before_current
        GROUP BY cte_ladder_value_before_current.member_id;

# 6. Get the rung value for the most recent ladder level BEFORE
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_ladder_level_before_current_period
        SELECT
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.member_id,
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_value,
        cte_leenk_ladder_history.date_trigger_event

        FROM cte_leenk_ladder_history
            INNER JOIN
                cte_ladder_date_before_current_period ON cte_leenk_ladder_history.member_id = cte_ladder_date_before_current_period.member_id
                AND cte_leenk_ladder_history.date_trigger_event = cte_ladder_date_before_current_period.date_trigger_event_max
        WHERE cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_change = 1 AND cte_leenk_ladder_history.ladder_value IS NOT NULL;

#### COUNT CURRENT & START OF PERIOD LADDER LEVELS, THEN DIFFERENCE 

# 7. addition counts
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_additions_to_current_rung
        SELECT
            cte_current_record_ladder_level.ladder_value,
            COUNT(cte_current_record_ladder_level.ladder_value) AS additions_to_current_rung

        FROM cte_current_record_ladder_level
        GROUP BY cte_current_record_ladder_level.ladder_value;

# 8. Start of Period COUNTs
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_start_of_period_count
        SELECT
            cte_ladder_level_before_current_period.ladder_value,
            COUNT(cte_ladder_level_before_current_period.ladder_value) AS start_of_period_count

        FROM cte_ladder_level_before_current_period
        GROUP BY cte_ladder_level_before_current_period.ladder_value;

# 9. SUM additions to rung + start of period additions 
        SELECT
            cte_additions_to_current_rung.ladder_value,
            additions_to_current_rung,
            start_of_period_count,
            additions_to_current_rung + start_of_period_count AS total_ladder_counts
        FROM cte_additions_to_current_rung
            INNER JOIN cte_start_of_period_count ON cte_additions_to_current_rung.ladder_value = cte_start_of_period_count.ladder_value;

# 10. LOST from rung
# count IDs where ladder_current <> ladder_beginning -- will talk about 12/12
   # SELECT
    #    cte_current_record_ladder_level.ladder_value as current_ladder_value, 
     #   cte_ladder_level_before_current_period.ladder_value as prior_ladder_value,
      #  count(cte_current_record_ladder_level.ladder_value) as count_current_ladder_value

   # FROM 
    #    cte_current_record_ladder_level
     #       INNER JOIN cte_ladder_level_before_current_period 
      #          ON cte_ladder_level_before_current_period.member_id = cte_ladder_level_before_current_period.member_id
       #     WHERE cte_current_record_ladder_level.ladder_value != cte_ladder_level_before_current_period.ladder_value
        ##   ORDER BY cte_current_record_ladder_level.ladder_value; 


#### END STORED PROCEDURE 
    END
```